# Does spartacus support ASM deep links?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

The Assisted Service Module provides [Deep links](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2005/en-US/c61971cf2c974fa3bb59fa7f3cca9878.html) functionality that allows starting emulation instantly. It's used in the customer support cockpit to launch a new ASM session.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obZsP.png)

The next pattern is used to generate the redirect url **{storefrontUrl}**/**{deepLinkValue}**?customerId=**{selectedCustomer}**&orderId=**{selectedOrder}**.

**{deepLinkValue}** - is taken from the property **assistedservicestorefront.deeplink.link**. It's not clear what value should be set for spartacus and whether spartacus supports this functionality or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that ASM Deep Links are currently supported in Spartacus.  If you look at the Spartacus code, the only thing that appears to trigger from URL parameters is AsmEnablerService, which is looking for asm=true (and adds the UI items for ASM into the display): https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/feature-libs/asm/root/services/asm-enabler.service.ts

Currently the ASM implementation in Spartacus is more limited than the Accelerator implementation. If you look at the published roadmap for Spartacus, you can see several of the additional features are referenced: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-roadmap/